# WinRT Async calls count quota

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

In my WinRT app occured next error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   WinRT information: Quota for maximum number of concurrent operations exceeded. Wait for an operation to complete before starting new ones.
>   Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time.

It always fails on lines like

```
await SaveImageAsync(imageMega, fileName);
```

I have a lot of async operation. May be there is a problem that I execute simultaneously a lot of async tasks?
If so, how can I handle it?

Answer (score -1):

Do you execute all your operations from a single piece of code? Or are they spread throughout the project?

If you can batch them, do so using `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.For`.
You can use `ParallelOptions`to limit the number of concurrent executions.
However, you'll have to do this synchronously:

```
List<ImageData> imgData = //...
Parallel.ForEach(imgData,
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
                 data => SaveImageAsync(data.imageMega, data.fileName)).Wait();
```

If you decide to go with this approach, I'd recommend not using async at all - change `async Task SaveImageAsync` to `void SaveImageAsync`.
If this method is using WInRT's file IO operations, you can make them synchronous using the `GetAwaiter` and `GetResult` methods:

```
var file = folder.GetFileAsync(Filename).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` doesn't work for `async` methods. It would basically limit how many async actions are *starting*, but not how many are really executing.

Comment: Synchronously waiting for async methods is a very bad idea too. 1. It blocks the UI thread, which is exactly what the whole async-await thing is trying to avoid. 2. It's very easy to cause deadlocks this way.

Comment: That really depends. If this piece of code is being executed within a task (or on its own thread) then it won't block the UI. And the only async call he would be blocking on would be IO calls like GetFyleAsync - if you use the awaiter like I suggested, you won't cause any deadlock.